# pipe the output of cat into a node script

Tags: bash, command-line, pipe

I am an absolute beginner at UNIX scripting (and have searched here for something explaining how to do this in a simple way to no avail). I am trying to pipe the contents of a `claimName.txt` file

```
find . -name 'claimName.txt' -exec cat {} \;
```

into a Node.js script that takes this value after a `-c` flag

```
npm run import -- -r ./ -c {claimName.txt contents go here}
```

What's the simplest way to pipe the `claimName.txt` contents to follow the `-c` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this without a pipe:

```
npm run import -- -r ./ -c "$(find . -name 'claimName.txt' -exec cat {} \; -quit)"
```

Comment: I know this wasn't in my original question, but is there a way to do this that strips out newlines?

Comment: Try to replace the `nmp..-c` part with `echo`. On my host the content of any file is displayed without newlines.

Comment: You force replacing newlines with spaces you can use `$(find . -name 'claimName.txt' -exec cat {} \;|tr '\n' ' ')`

Comment: well, if you can do it without a pipe, you haven't demonstrated how here. and the dump of an entire text file *(at least)* into an unquoted substitution is straight-up crazy.

Comment: Fun fact: It's technically not a pipeless solution. Process substitution uses (system level) pipes internally.

Comment: It would be cool if you explained each flag you added.